# package import and NameError

Tags: python, python-2.7, namespaces, python-import

I have some troubles with importation of self-made modules, I just can't see what I am doing wrong.

I have a package named basics, which has all my base classes
I have a second package named components, and every module in componentsuses the modules from basics.
I have a script file, located in another folder, which calls upon the basics and components modules.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "H:/scripts/CIF_utilities/scripts/hello world.py", line 11, in <module>
    TW=TextWriter(r'H:/scripts/CIF_utilities/components')
  File "H:\scripts\CIF_utilities\components\textwriter.py", line 23, in __init__
    layout=Layout(File=os.path.join(path,'alphabet.CIF'))
NameError: global name 'Layout' is not defined
```

There is my script: hello world.py

```
#hello world.py
import basics
from components.textwriter import *

TW=TextWriter(r'H:/scripts/CIF_utilities/components')

cell=TW.writeText('Hello World',30e3)
cell.draw()

layout=Layout()
layout.addCell(cell)
layout.workCell=cell

layout.exportCIF('hello world',os.getcwd())
```

textwriter.py is the one giving the error. In **init**, I load some data from a preformatted file using the Layout class (which will make the import)
in textwriter.py

```
#texwriter.py
import basics
import os, os.path, sys
import re
from numpy import *
from scipy import *


class TextWriter:

    def __init__(self,pathToCIF=None):
        if pathToCIF==None:
            path=os.path.split(textwriter.__file__)[0]
        else:
            path=pathToCIF            

        ###line that crashes is here        

        layout=Layout(File=os.path.join(path,'alphabet.CIF'))
        self.alphabet=layout.workCell
```

There is the layout.py class:

```
#layout.py
import basics
from numpy import *
from scipy import *
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import os, os.path
import re
import datetime

class Layout:
    countCell=0
    @classmethod
    def getNewNumber(self):
        Layout.countCell+=1
        return Layout.countCell


    def __init__(self,File=None):
        self.cellList=[]
        self.layerList=[]
        self.nameFile=""
        self.comments=""
        self.workCell=None

        if File!=None:
            self.importCIF(File)
```

the **init**.py of the basics package contains all the necessary importations:

```
#__init__.py in basics folder
from baseElt import *
from cell import *
from layout import *
from transformation import *
```

the **init**.py from components is empty

I am currently using the anaconda 64bits distribution (python 2.7 if I recall well)

Thanks for your much needed help!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `basics.Layout(...)` (or `from basics import Layout`)?

Comment: I changed the "import basics" to "from basics import *", and now it works! I will try again with some more advanced script to see if it works for that as well

Answer (score 1):

Since `Layout` is imported in `basics/__init__.py`, it only exists in the `basics` namespace, not in `helloworld.py`. Either access it with

```
layout = basics.Layout()
```

or explicitly import `Layout` into `helloworld.py` with

```
from basics import Layout
```

Answer (score 0):

In textwriter.py, you want to switch

```
layout=Layout(File=os.path.join(path,'alphabet.CIF'))
```

for

```
layout=basics.Layout(File=os.path.join(path,'alphabet.CIF'))
```

You may have similar problems along your code.  it is good to note that it is not pythonic to use

```
from package import *
```

It is recommended to instead use

```
from package_or_module import specific_item
import package_or_module
```

Remember, if you import with regular `import` you have to use the module/package name to access the object you want (i.e. `basics.Layout`).